# Receiving wrong results via using sort_values() on a data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(result_list)
dfObj.columns = ['INCIDENT', 'ASSIGNED TO'"] 
dfObj.sort_values(by='ASSIGNED TO')
print(dfObj)
```

Output:

```
      INCIDENT      ASSIGNED TO  
0   INC1899203    Karun Sheemar   
1   INC1900599    Samarth Karan   
2   INC1900757     Ayushi Saini   
3   INC1900648   Rachit Rastogi   
4   INC1899084    Samarth Karan   
5   INC1899335     Yogesh Nehra   
6   INC1900688     Ayushi Saini   
7   INC1900636    Himanjali Roy   
8   INC1898703    Vedanshi Jain
```

> If you closely review the output, you can clearly see that data is not sorted and is messed up. I am trying to sort the data frame on the basis of the name so that I can send mail once to the concerned person using flow control.

Comment: Why sorting the list if you actually want to drop duplicates ? Have a look at [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: Add `inplace=True` or reassign the sorted a variable

Comment: @AlexandreB. I do not wish to drop any entry as data here does not contain any duplicate value. Thank you for the prompt response.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Also, you can, and should, assign the column names when creating the DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

you should mention `inplace=True` while sorting or save it in new dataframe

```
new_df=dfObj.sort_values(by='ASSIGNED TO')
```

OR

```
dfObj.sort_values(by='ASSIGNED TO', inplace =True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dfObj.sort_values(by='ASSIGNED TO',inplace=True)
```

> Its working fine now. Thank you everyone.